# Listen for Query failed due to insufficient user permision

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I want to build an chat app. Now for a month like so my app was working fine but suddenly its showing the following error while querying and data from Firebase.

> W/Firestore(11249): (24.1.2) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(chatRoom where usersarray_containsSayan Banerjee order by **name**);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

The above error shows when I want to query the list of users with whom I used to chat. For a split second the desirable list is displayed, but then immediately the above error shows and I get a blank screen.

Similar error arise whenever I try to query the list of users and all that.

I am attaching the GitHub repo link for my project too.
I would be highly thankful if you help me.

GITHUB REPO: https://github.com/SayanBanerjee09082002/chatapp

Comment: Please show the security rules you're using.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably somebody used `test mode` when the database was created.

> Your data is open by default to enable quick setup. However, you must update your security rules within 30 days to enable long-term client read/write access.

Comment: Ok yes so the test mode was on and  I have not updated the security rules. Now the problem is solved. Thanks.